# glutTimerFunc issues

Tags: c++, glut

I am using a timer function to animate, but I am having issues when I place it in the Renderer class.

```
void Renderer::animate(int value)
{
 glutTimerFunc(TIMERMSECS, animate, 0);
}
```

Error:
\renderer.cpp(242) : error C3867: 'Renderer::animate': function call missing argument list; use '&Renderer::animate' to create a pointer to member

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that `Renderer::animate` is a class member function and so has a hidden `this` parameter.  `glutTimerFunc` doesn't know what value of `this` to pass, so if you somehow tried to sneak past the compiler with a nasty cast, it would crash at runtime.

The solution is to change `Renderer::animate` into a static method or an ordinary global function.  You then need to store the pointer to your `Renderer` instance in a global variable, e.g.:

```
class Renderer
{
    static void staticAnimate(int value);
    void animate(int value);
    ...
};
Renderer *gRenderer = ...;

void Renderer::staticAnimate(int value)
{
    gRenderer->animate(value);
}

...

glutTimerFunc(TIMERMSECS, &Renderer::staticAnimate, 0);
```

If `sizeof(void*) <= sizeof(int)` (true on 32-bit systems but not true on 64-bit systems), then you could also pass the instance via the `value` parameter; however, since this is not portable and you won't ever need to call `glutTimerFunc` on multiple different instances simultaneously, you shouldn't have to worry about using a global variable for this.

Comment: for gRenderer im getting this ->

error C2227: left of '->animate' must point to class/struct/union/generic type

error C2227: left of '->animate' must point to class/struct/union/generic type

Answer (score 1):

[`glutTimerFunc()`](http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/documentation/manual/glutTimerFunc.3GLUT.html) expects a pointer to a function of type `void (*func)(int value)`, not a member function of type `void (Renderer::*func)(int value)`.

Make `Render::animate` static or use a global function.