# How to pass a non-static function to glutTimerFunc?

Tags: c++, timer, c++17, glut, freeglut

I need to use `glutTimerFunc` in a class because I want it to run on each class instance separately. I have found two questions similar to this one but I still don't know how to implement that. I know that there is a hidden `this` before all static functions that `glutTimerFunc` is not aware of. There is this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35855156/12850027) that shows how to use `std::function` to be able to make a lambda function and pass it to the timer function, but I was not able to implement this and the answer doesn't mention `glutTimerFunc`. There is also this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3939663/12850027) but it is not so clear and the answer doesn't seem to work.

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Traditional solution is to make a static function that takes an instance of the object as a user parameter, casts the parameter to the correct type, and then invokes the appropriate member function. Not sure if this is an option here, but it'd be a pretty dumb callback function if you can't.

Comment: Thie timer function callback should have only one parameter and it should be int glutTimerFunc(int, void(*)(int), int) I will not be able to pass class instances as a parameter to the static function.

Comment: You do get to pass in an int. maybe you can use the `int` as a look-up into a map of instances.

Comment: I have implemented that before, and it works, but this is not what I want. I want the instance to run the timer on its own because that will make things way less complicated since I have so many functions in the class that needs a timer and the class itself has an intermediate class that controls it, it gets complicated you know. If no answer is found for this problem, I will just have to call the timer with the instance function from where I initialized the instance and that would work, but just to simplify things I need this.

Comment: @GeorgeA....: "*I want the instance to run the timer on its own*" You're dealing with a 3-decade old C API that has no idea what C++ even is, let alone knows what an "instance" of a "class" is. So you're going to have to adapt to its needs. It provides a mechanism for you to identify which timer you registered, so that's what you have available. If you're not willing to use the API tools you're given, then I suggest moving on to an API that isn't terrible. Seriously, GLUT is useful only for demo apps, not anything where you would need dozens of timers.

Comment: Even 30 years ago providing a `void * userp` in a C callback interface was pretty much de rigueur. I don't know why the designers would have left it out except for some performance implication that I don't see or to dumb down the interface for the masses. But what is, is.

Comment: @Nicol Bolas That is a very good explanation Unfortunately, I cannot use a different API because it is a school assignment. Do you recommend any alternative C++ library I can use to implement the timer functionality on class instances?